# How to keep file names when using diff with regex

Tags: regular-expression, diff

I am using this diff to show whether two files differ, but I need the regex to ignore the lines that are different that I don't care about. But the way it is set up it changes the names of the files when it reports a difference.

```
diff -q --suppress-common-lines -B <(grep -vE '\s(name|timestamp|root)=' goldcopy.xml)  <(grep -vE '(\sname|timestamp|root)=' QJ03425234.xml)
```

It reports something like "Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 differ", but I need it to be the file names so if someone does not know what files it ran with they can still know what files are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What diff actually compares in your oneliner, are not the files but the output of `grep`. For each of those two file descriptors dynamically are created by shell (bash), `/dev/fd/63` `/dev/fd/62` are they usual names. `<( command )` idiom is known as [process substituion](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html),
So there's no direct way for `diff` to know the original file names, unless you tell it that explicitly. Consider using `--label` or `-L` option

```
F1=goldcopy.xml; F2=QJ03425234.xml;  diff  -L $F1  -q --suppress-common-lines -B <(grep -vE '\s(name|timestamp|root)=' $F1)  -L $F2 <(grep -vE '(\sname|timestamp|root)=' $F2)
```